# Javascript unexpected token

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I made this code for some testing and I was going to link a Github script to it. But when I tried it, it did not work.

```
const request = url => fetch(url).then(res => res.text());

const injectInline = (data) => {
    data = data.replace(new RegExp("\r?\n", "g"), "")
    data = data.replace(/ +/g, " ");
    let s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.innerText = data;
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(s);
};

(async function() {
    let script = await request(`github link`);
    injectInline((script));
})();

let observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
    for (const mutation of mutations) {
        for (let node of mutation.addedNodes) {
            if (node.tagName == 'SCRIPT' && node.src.includes("c14.js")) {
                node.outerHTML = ``;
            }
        }
    }
});

.observe(document, {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
});
```

When I run this code, it throws the following error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'`

Comment: The line numbers here only serve to clutter things up and serve no useful purpose. They're best removed. Just add a comment on the line in question.

Comment: "Didn't work" isn't a technical description of your problem. What happened? Did you see any errors in your JavaScript console? Did you get unexpected results?

Comment: "Unexpected token" usually means what you're injecting has a syntax error. Did you fetch the *raw* JavaScript or something wrapped in HTML?

Comment: Please follow [these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question formatting

Comment: Is .observe supposed to be like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to SO. At first glance, there is a `;` that shouldn't be here in the last lines. Here's your updated code :

```js
const request = url => fetch(url).then(res => res.text());

const injectInline = (data) => {
    data = data.replace(new RegExp("\r?\n", "g"), "")
    data = data.replace(/ +/g, " ");
    let s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.innerText = data;
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(s);
};

(async function() {
    let script = await request(`github link`);
    injectInline((script));
})();

let observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
    for (const mutation of mutations) {
        for (let node of mutation.addedNodes) {
            if (node.tagName == 'SCRIPT' && node.src.includes("c14.js")) {
                node.outerHTML = ``;
            }
        }
    }
})
.observe(document, {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra semicolon in your code; You should do this:

```
const request = url => fetch(url).then(res => res.text());

const injectInline = (data) => {
    data = data.replace(new RegExp("\r?\n", "g"), "")
    data = data.replace(/ +/g, " ");
    let s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.innerText = data;
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(s);
};

(async function() {
    let script = await request(`github link`);
    injectInline((script));
})();

let observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
    for (const mutation of mutations) {
        for (let node of mutation.addedNodes) {
            if (node.tagName == 'SCRIPT' && node.src.includes("c14.js")) {
                node.outerHTML = ``;
            }
        }
    }
})
.observe(document, {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
});
```